# NGINX secure link not working

Tags: nginx

I setup NGINX on CentOS and set config file to prevent direct access video file.
This is example code that I use.

```
    location /videos/ {
    valid_referers none blocked abccc.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }   
     root      /var/cdn/videos/;

    ## This must match the URI part related to the MD5 hash and expiration time.
    secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;      
    ## The MD5 hash is built from our secret token, the URI($path in PHP) and our expiration time.
    secure_link_md5 Gf1Pv52EifS1f8G9agn2k2n8a$uri$arg_e;         
    ## If the hash is incorrect then $secure_link is a null string.
    if ($secure_link = "") {
        return 403;
    }        
    ## The current local time is greater than the specified expiration time.
    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        return 403;
    }

    gzip off;
    gzip_static off;
    mp4;
    flv;
    mp4_buffer_size        5M;
    mp4_max_buffer_size    10M;
    #mp4_limit_rate        on;
    #mp4_limit_rate_after  30s;     

    ## If everything is ok $secure_link is 1.
    rewrite ^/videos/(.*)$ /videos/$1 break;
}
```

But when restart server and test it, I still access video file in folder via
direct url and secure link.

Other wise when I try to use this configuration in localhost, it work perfectly.

What's I do wrong?

Comment: The replacement link in your rewrite rule doesn't seem to change the URL pattern that gets matched. Are you sure you have it correct?